# Eclipse: how can I copy code WITHOUT selection highlighting?

Tags: c, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

If I copy a block of code in C and paste it into Word, the syntax highlighting works well. But if I copy a single word on a line, the selection ("highlight") is also copied, meaning that the text pasted into Word is dark blue, and almost unreadable.

The fix seems to be to copy the entire line including the EOL char, then the "selection" part goes away.

I used InsideClipboard to view the RTF of each case, and the single word selection version has a "\highlight2" tag around the text. That seems to be the issue.

Is there a way of getting rid of this, while retaining the other- actually useful- syntax highlighting?

Bad: (if I copy just the selected word "FooText")

```
{\highlight2 
    {\cf0 }
    {\cf0\b FooText\b0}
}
```

Good: (if I copy the entire selected line, including EOL)

```
{\cf0 FooTex}
{\cf0\ul t\ul0}
```

Comment: hmm, maybe a bug in eclipse...

Comment: Most likely. V4.2.1 (CodeWarrior). Unfortunately this is the latest CW release.

Comment: Typically both the RTF and plain text versions will be placed in the Clipboard, with the application you're pasting into choosing which version to use. See if Word has a Paste Special action, or some other variation.

Comment: Yeah that's the trick. I use it in Excel all the time, never looked for it in Word. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. There is probably a bug in this version of Eclipse causing the highlighting to be incorrect / inconsistent
2. You can paste as text-only in Word using Paste-Options (Ctrl-Alt-V)